# What were the parameters set by Jesus to measure greatness of a student vis-a-vis the teacher as in Mt 10:24-25

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, knowledge, teacher

We read in Mtt 10:24-25 (NIV):

The student is not above the teacher, nor a servant above his master.  It is enough for students to be like their teachers, and servants like their masters.

It is clear that Jesus is not referring to the accumulation of worldly knowledge as a parameter of  greatness when he compares the student with the teacher. With abundant sources of knowledge outside the school/college, an excellent student can  outplay the teacher in so far as worldly knowledge is concerned. My question therefore is: What were the parameters set by Jesus to measure greatness of a student vis-a-vis the teacher as in Mt 10:24-25?

Inputs from any denomination are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesus demonstrated what he meant by girding himself with a towel at the last supper, then getting on his knees to wash the disciples' feet. Then he explained the significance of this action (just hours before he was to be betrayed).

> "Know ye what I have done unto you? Ye call me Master and Lord: and ye
> say well, for so I am. If I then, your Lord and Master, have washed
> your feet, ye also ought to wash one another's feet. For I have given
> you an example, that ye should do as I have done to you.
>
> Verily, verily, I say unto you, The servant is not greater than his
> Lord; neither he that is sent greater than he that sent him. If ye
> know these things, happy are ye if ye do them." John 13:12-17 K.J.V.

Humbly serving others, like Jesus did, is a parameter of greatness. "The Son of Man did not come to be served, but to serve"  Matthew 20:28

Another parameter is being hated as Jesus was hated.

> "If the world hate you, ye know that it hated me before it hated you.
> If ye were of the world, the world would love his own; but because ye
> are not of the world, but I have chosen you out of the world,
> therefore the world hateth you. Remember the word that I said unto
> you, The servant is not greater than his lord. If they have persecuted
> me, they will also persecute you." John 15:18-20 K.J.V.

So another identifying mark of students of Christ who will be considered "great" in the kingdom is being hated and persecuted by worldly people, and for this reason - they are seen by worldly people as followers of Jesus and not followers of the world.

A third parameter is following Jesus' example by not clinging on to life but by being prepared to give up one's life for Jesus' sake, remembering that he died for them. This is what Jesus said:

> "He that loveth his life shall lose it; and he that hateth his life in
> this world shall keep it unto life eternal. If any man serve me, let
> him follow me; and where I am, there shall also my servant be: if any
> man serve me, him will my Father honour." John 12:25-26 K.J.V.

Finally, a fourth parameter involves servanthood. James and John asked Jesus to grant them to sit at his right and left sides in the kingdom. Jesus called all the disciples to him and said:

> "Ye know that they which are accounted to rule over the Gentiles
> exercise lordship over them; and their great ones exercise authority
> upon them. But so shall it not be among you: but whosoever will be
> great among you, shall be your minister. And whosoever of you will be
> the chiefest, shall be servant of all. For even the Son of man came
> not to be ministered unto, but to minister, and to give his life a
> ransom for many." Mark 10:42-45

Servanthood, not lordship, is the path to greatness in God's economy. The world’s way of ‘lording it over others’ must have no place amongst students of the Great Teacher.

Answer (score 3):

Context is provided at the end of v25; "If they have called the master of the house Beelzebul, how much more will they malign those of his household" (RSV). The words which you have quoted are leading up to that conclusion.

The implication is that "greatness" in this context is about immunity to unjust criticism. If the "greater" teacher and master does not have it, then the "lesser" disciples and servants won't have it either. In fact they are even more likely to suffer in this way.

The larger context is that the twelve disciples are being sent out to minister to the people of the land in the same way that Jesus has been doing (ch10 v1). The charge that Jesus was acting "by the prince of demons" is mentioned in ch9 v34, just previously, but is answered in the story which Matthew records in ch12 vv22-32. What *should* have given Jesus immunity from false criticism in that situation was his authority. The critics should have known that he was sent by God; "It is by the Spirit of God that I cast out demons" (ch12 v28).

The authority of the disciples is less (being delegated) and also less obvious, and that is what makes them more vulnerable. So perhaps the answer to your question is that "visible authority" is the parameter. This works for both comparisons (teacher/disciple and master/servant).